# wxExecute without a terminal window pop up

Tags: wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxExecute this way: 
    wxExecute("taskkill /F /IM ASServer.exe");

and I don't intend to see the terminal window that pops up(windows). Is there a way to do that?
except this http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxExecute

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The way given on the wiki page you linked to is the standard way of doing it, but if you really can't stand it the following should work:

```
wxProcess process;
wxExecute("taskkill /F /IM ASServer.exe", wxEXEC_ASYNC, &process);
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.9 (I don't think it existed in 2.8), just pass `wxEXEC_HIDE_CONSOLE` flag to `wxExecute()`.